# Get Specific Data From JSON Where filtered by the values PHP

Tags: php, json

```
[
   {
      "team_id":"812b4ba287f5ee0bc9d43bbf5bbe87fb",
      "group":1
   },
   {
      "team_id":"66f041e16a60928b05a7e228a89c3799",
      "group":1
   },
   {
      "team_id":"c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5",
      "group":1
   },
   {
      "team_id":"85d8ce590ad8981ca2c8286f79f59954",
      "group":5
   },
   {
      "team_id":"6974ce5ac660610b44d9b9fed0ff9548",
      "group":5
   },
   {
      "team_id":"1afa34a7f984eeabdbb0a7d494132ee5",
      "group":5
   }
]
```

I have that JSON, how do i get the data where the team_id is '812b4ba287f5ee0bc9d43bbf5bbe87fb' with php?

I cant do it by [0] because the json is always shuffle the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first of all parse the JSON-Text and verify the expectation that it is an array:

```php
$json = json_decode($jsonText, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
if (!is_array($json)) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException('Expected array, got ' . gettype($json));
}
```

*(just showing it for brevity, you are likely already aware of it)*

Next you bring the array into a form that is beneficial for getting the data you want. E.g. you don't know the index by number (and can't as it is unstable), but what if the index would be the string you're looking for?

```php
$teamIdMap = array_column($json, null, 'team_id');

print_r($teamIdMap['1afa34a7f984eeabdbb0a7d494132ee5'] ?? null, false);
```

Here [`array_column`](https://php.net/array_column) is exactly for that. It turns the array into a map of team-ids to the team-data, see the output:

```
Array
(
    [team_id] => 1afa34a7f984eeabdbb0a7d494132ee5
    [group] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_filter` on the decoded associative array.

```
$filteredArray = array_filter(json_decode($yourJSONString, true), function($val) {
    return $val['team_id'] === '812b4ba287f5ee0bc9d43bbf5bbe87fb';
});
```